# Matching string with regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to create a function that accesses if a user entered username matches a regular expression. Here is my code:

```
def regular_expression():
    rules = "[A-Z]^{1}[a-zA-Z0-9]+[0-9]$"

    while True:
        username = str(input("Username Must have:\n"
                             "- First character must be an upper case letter\n"
                             " - Middle can be any letter or number\n"
                             "- Last character must be a number\n"
                             "> "
                             ))

        if re.fullmatch(rules, username):
            print("Accepted")
```

This is the error I receive:

```
    return _compile(pattern, flags).fullmatch(string)
    p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)
    p = sre_parse.parse(p, flags)
    p = _parse_sub(source, pattern, flags & SRE_FLAG_VERBOSE, 0)
    source.tell() - here + len(this))
re.error: multiple repeat at position 9
```

Comment: One can't quantify start of string. You need to remove the `^` and `$` as you are using `re.fullmatch`. Also, remove `{1}`, it is always redundant.

Comment: And there are some string length questions remaining (if it can be 1- or 2-char long?)

Comment: Please clarify the requirements to relieve any doubts regarding the actual intentions here. Does `rules = "[A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]+[0-9]"` work?

Comment: You need to update your rules to this `rules = "[A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]+[0-9]$"` , And you can remove the ^ symbol:  because the re.fullmatch function will match the entire string.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `^{1}` that inside your `rules` variable, what the purpose of it?

I managed to make this work with this:

```
def regular_expression():
    rules = "[A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]+[0-9]$"

while True:
    username = str(input("Username Must have:\n"
                         "- First character must be an upper case letter\n"
                         " - Middle can be any letter or number\n"
                         "- Last character must be a number\n"
                         "> "
                         ))

    if re.fullmatch(rules, username):
        print("Accepted")
    else:
        print("Invalid username")
```

Comment: While this answer seems right but you don't need to add the break because it already waits for next input so you don't want to break from that loop.

Comment: Why would the loop still run if we found a correct username format?

Comment: Because its for checking multiple users thats how the user designed it why would there be while loop at first place. And why you need While loop and break you can just use If statements then.

Comment: I think the author had in mind that if you don't enter UserName by the rules, you will have another chance to fix it(same idea in Creating Gmail account- username is already used, try another one etc.)
Anyhow both of us are trying hard to understand the real use cases of this Q without real justification, I think we will let the author express what was in his mind haha

Comment: He just wanted to give Max retries until the Valid username is not entered then it will automatically exit from loop and would bring Homepage in real application.